# How does Google Analytics track re-entry into a goal funnel?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, goal-tracking, goals

How does Google Analytics tracks users? Is each user is tracked as unique user?

I have a doubt about a goal flow in Google Analytics. I'm working on an ecommerce site. I set the goal as reach the "thank you" page after purchasing something. Before reaching the thank you page, users have to complete a checkout process. My doubt is about what happen if a user leaves the checkout process and comes back to site for add to cart another object and then returns to checkout and completes the order? What would I see on the goal flow? Would it be 2 entries into the checkout process (the first access and then the second one, after the user has added something to the cart) and 1 abandonment?

I want to know if the user which has leave the checkout process and the user which completes the order is the same user. How can I track this?

Answer (score 1):

Goal Flow report let you see data based on *pageviews*, so you can analyze page by page. It's not like funnel visualization that is *visits* based.

So, in that scenario, your visitor would report as an exit in the first visit, then as a goal completed in the second.

More here:
http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2012/08/06/goal-flow-how-visitors-really-move-through-funnel/
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2976313?hl=en